# Google Play Games returns false on Social.localUser.Authenticate

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

Hello: I've been wrestling a bit with getting my app to authenticate. I've deployed the APK to my Galaxy and the following happens: Unity game opens, "Connecting to..." dialog appears, "Google Play" green dialog appears, dialog disappears with loading indicator and then I get a "false" result.

I have the following in Start():

```
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    AuthenticateGoogle();
```

And the following in AuthenticateGoogle():

```
private bool AuthenticateGoogle()
{
    isAuthorized = false;
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool result) => {
        isAuthorized = result;
        if (!result)
        {
            GameObject.Find("errText").GetComponent<Text>().text = result.ToString();
        }
    });
    return isAuthorized;
}
```

I created a new Keystore using the Unity UI, entered the password and built the .APK. I then created a new application in the Google Play Console and uploaded the .APK to it. I next created a new Game Service and linked the app, allowing it to Trust the application. I created a leaderboard. I ensured my user is in the Testing section. Lastly I copied the XML from the Get resources section under leaderboard to my Unity project and built the project, copying to my phone.

Any ideas? Any other things I can do to troubleshoot authentication versus a true/false result?

Comment: When I linked my app I got a new client identity (ending in .apps.googleusercontent.com). Do I need to do anything with that in Unity to link the build of my app?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are testing it on your android phone.

You should try adding this to your android mainfest:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

You can create custom mainfest in Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidMainfest.xml

Add yourself to testers on Google Play Console (if the app is in beta) and download it directly through google play. (not test build and run)

To track errors like this you can use a tool https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/log-viewer-12047 It's simple to use and you can understand what went wrong. Hope it'll help :)

EDIT:

I'm using different method, but it shouldn't make a difference:

```
 public bool ConnectToGoogleServices()
{
    if (!isConnectedToGoogleServices)
    {
        {
            Social.localUser.Authenticate(success =>
                {
                    isConnectedToGoogleServices = success;
                });
        }
    }
    return isConnectedToGoogleServices;
}
```

Comment: The GooglePlayGames manifest included (Assets/GooglePlayGames/Plugins/Android/GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin) has the activity line you referenced above so I wasn't sure if I need to make the referenced change you specified. I did install the log-viewer tool. On my Note it states "Creating Android IPlayGames Client client"..."Starting Auth Tansition. Op: SIGN_IN status:ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED"..."There are pending auth callback-starting AuthUI"..."Starting Auth Transition. ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED"..."AuthState == Unathenticating calling auth callbacks with failure." Nothing seems to be standing out.